# SQL with clause multiple results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i am fighting with `with clause` two return a result set as well as set a sql variable too.
Or somehow i just want to get two results from the `with clause`.
My sql query is:

```
declare @total as int

;with T as
(
    // some sql query
)
select * from T
```

above query returning a set of result, But i also want to set `@total` (number of rows in T).
Is this possible ? Thank you

Here is also a way two do this like :

```
;with T as
    (
        select count(1), * from table1
    )
    select * from T
```

But its not a appropriate way to do this, Because it will return the `count` as `column`.

Comment: Why you need the total count from inside the CTE since it will be available in the outer select: `select * from T`.

Comment: @techdo: from outer select i only able to get the one thing either result set or count, But i want both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear how you're calling this from your question. Is it via a stored procedure, ADO.NET or something else all together?

I'm not sure how you'd expect to get your variable set within the CTE. I'm not aware of any way to do that.

Maybe use your CTE to populate a table variable with the results and then set your count of rows in the table variable as an out parameter if you're using a stored procedure that is.

Alternatively, you could maybe use @@ROWCOUNT after selecting the results from CTE. [See this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995589/set-nocount-off-or-return-rowcount/995603#995603) as an example.

Testing @@ROWCOUNT with your example above yields the results and a separate count of the results returned. See below;

```
DECLARE @Total AS INT

;WITH T AS 
(
SELECT 2 AS a
UNION
SELECT 4
UNION
SELECT 6
UNION
SELECT 8
) SELECT * FROM T

SET @Total = (SELECT @@ROWCOUNT)

SELECT @Total
```

Comment: just what i needed !!. Thank you @Mr Moose.

Comment: No probs. Glad I could be of some help.

Comment: I put together an example how to use the WITH clause to create a temporary static table using a similar approach:

http://www.giombetti.com/2014/02/14/using-sql-with-clause-to-create-temporary-static-tables-at-query-time/

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query:

```
select 
    count(*) over() [Count], 
    * 
From T
```

Comment: i think i already suggested this way as inappropriate in my question above, Please see. Thank you